# Where can the latest maps marking all dangerous areas be found?

Tags: flight-planning

I'd like to be aware of and include areas (in the requested maps) that might not be prohibited, but discriminated, mentioned, singularised, or warned in any way. An example: http://www.newrepublic.com/article/118764/map-faa-tells-airlines-avoid-flying-over-these-countries

Comment: It sounds like you want a [mashup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashup_(web_application_hybrid)) of FlightRadar24, SkyVector, the FAA NOTAM website and a NOTAM decoder.

Comment: `I'd like to include` where?

Comment: @LePressentiment No. You say you'd "like to include areas that [might be bad]". Include them in *what*?

Comment: @Federico Better?

Comment: The term "dangerous" means different things to different people.

Comment: I've flagged this question as a duplicate, because any accepted answer to the other question will also include enough information to answer this one.