# Where can a realtime map showing all flights and all dangerous areas be found?

Tags: flight-planning

Further to [my other question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7830/128), how can I find a realtime map of all flights that's combined with the foregoing map of all perilous zones? My goal is to see which flights may be overflying them, and in particular, if there are any commercial flights doing so.

For example, I only learnt of this via CNN, but want to predetermine this by myself: http://edition.cnn.com/2014/07/22/world/asia/malaysia-airlines-plane-over-syria/

Comment: all current flights is [flightradar24.com](http://www.flightradar24.com); NOTAMed areas you'll have to compile yourself

Comment: To answer part of the question: [Apart from Kenya, what are the current dangerous / unsafe airspaces?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39461/1696)

Answer (score 2):

Actually what constitutes a "perilous zone" is arbitrarily decided by countries or airlines . Ergo, there are no zones that have been defined by the International Civil Aviation Organization as perilous .

http://www.icao.int/Pages/default.aspx

For example as on this date British Airways and Qantas  have demarcated Ukrainian airspace as dangerous and is therefore avoiding it .

As far as a realtime map of flights are concerned who may take a look at Flightradar24

http://www.flightradar24.com/20,77/7