# Apart from Kenya, what are the current dangerous / unsafe airspaces?

Tags: safety, airspace, notam

Notams are regularly released to warn about unsafe areas, e.g. Kenya:

> A0040/15 
>   - SECURITY .. UNITED STATES OF AMERICA ADVISORY TO U.S. OPERATORS 
>   CONCERNING POSSIBLE ATTACKS WITH MAN - PORTABLE AIR DEFENSE SYSTEMS 
>   (MANPADS)
>
> ATTENTION U.S. OPERATORS: INFORMATION INDICATES THE POTENTIAL FOR 
>   TERRORIST ATTACK AGAINST U.S. AND WESTERN INTERESTS IN KENYA.
>   WHILE SPECIFIC DETAILS ARE NOT AVAILABLE, ONE POSSIBLE TACTIC WOULD 
>   BE AN ATTACK USING MAN - PORTABLE AIR DEFENSE SYSTEMS (MANPADS), 
>   SUCH AS THOSE USED AGAINST AN ISRAELI AIR CARRIER DEPARTING FROM MOMBASA,
>   KENYA ON NOVEMBER 28, 2002.
>   THE DEPARTMENT OF STATE HAS ISSUED A TRAVEL WARNING FOR KENYA REGARDING 
>   TERRORIST ATTACKS.

Is there a list of these hazardous airspaces, or a site than can be checked without searching in Notams from around the world? Is there a ranking of the hazards?

Answer (score 9):

I feel there is more to say than currently answered, feel free to reuse part or all of this content to build an improved answer which could be selected.

---

There are recaps of flight restrictions, e.g. French DGAC publishes maps and [plain text files](https://www.ecologique-solidaire.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/AIC-en.pdf) recapitulating areas, in addition of individual NOTAMS:

[image]
<sup>Source: [DGAC](https://www.ecologique-solidaire.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/Carte%20interdictions%20survols_GB.pdf)</sup>

ICAO announced in 2015 the creation of a specific member-collaborative tool [CZRI, conflict zones risk information](https://www.icao.int/czir/Pages/default.aspx) (currently very poor).

EASA also publishes a [list of conflict zones bulletins](https://ad.easa.europa.eu/czib-docs/page-1) that can be [exported as pdf](https://ad.easa.europa.eu/czib-docs/page-1?format=pdf&r=20), and [a map](https://www.easa.europa.eu/easa-and-you/international-cooperation/easa-by-country/conflict-zones):

[image]

There are also other initiatives, e.g. [SafeAirspace](http://safeairspace.net/information/about-safeairspace/) with text summary and maps. "*SafeAirspace is managed by Flight Service Bureau, with contributions from The Airline Cooperative (225 international airlines), OpsGroup (1500 members), International Ops Bulletin feedback (40,000 readers), and data from the German BMVI, the UK DFT, the FAA, DGAC France, ICAO, and EASA.*"

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should always check NOTAMs when you fly. It is a must for safe operation.

However if you are just interested in hot spots on international scale you can check https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/us_restrictions/

It provide many interesting informations about worldwide hotspot in the eyes of FAA.

For local hotspot try: http://tfr.faa.gov/tfr2/list.html