# Is there any agency or meeting, at global level, that rules flight zone interdictions?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations, regulations

Considering the number of conflicts in the world, and the tragic event of the airliner crash over Ukrainia caused by military action, there are a lot of flight interdiction zones on the world.

From the data I gathered, those interdictions are pronounced by regional agencies, such as the FAA for the USA or the ESA for Europe. However, some countries like United Arab Emirates or Qatar have airline companies, but I don't think they have agencies such as the FAA. Still, do airplanes for those companues fly over East Ukraine?

So the question is:

- Is there any global agency that coordinates the questions of dangerous flight zones?
- Is it able to enforce an interdiction, or does it just put up meetings to coordinate the FAA, ESA and airline companies?

Comment: Related: [Who decided which airspaces not to fly through and how?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45672/1696) and [Where can a realtime map showing all flights and all dangerous areas be found](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/7831/1696)

Comment: Related: [Apart from Kenya, what are the current dangerous / unsafe airspaces?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39461/14897)

Comment: I will ask again the question since in the other question's answer, only country authorities are mentionned and not FAA, ESA or similar ones

Comment: Instead of closing, I think just answering "no there are not such global authorities" would have been good :)

Comment: Nit: Every country has a Civil Aviation Authority, usually called something similar to that generic term in the national language.